# How to get Gridsome Image path in the main.js file

Tags: vue.js, gridsome, vue-meta

My website is missing og:image tags and is not showing images on LinkedIn. 
The solution is to Add the meta tag which I have added however once the project gets built and deployd the name of the images change.

I am looking for something liek this, but where the image would be replaced by the actual generated image path like the ones in g-image

```
export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
   ....

  head.meta.push({
    name: 'image',
    property: 'og:image',
    content: './src/banner.jpg'
  })

  ....
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the images in the `static/` folder? https://gridsome.org/docs/directory-structure/#the-static-directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your sample code, so I will show you my Blog source code.

It is simple. Let's say I'm querying the GraphQL with this query:

```
<page-query>
query Post ($id: ID!) {
  post: post (id: $id) {
    title
    description
    content
    cover_image (width: 860, blur: 10)
  }
}
</page-query>
```

So you have the `cover_image` you want to get the real path. The `g-image` components knows how to get it:

```xml
<g-image alt="Cover image" v-if="$page.post.cover_image" :src="$page.post.cover_image" />
```

But in your code, you just need to access to the `src` property:

```js
export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
   ....

  head.meta.push({
    name: 'image',
    property: 'og:image',
    content: this.$page.post.cover_image.src
  })

  ....
}
```

You can try to add a `img` element in your `template` just to make sure it is the right image:

```xml
<img :src="$page.post.cover_image.src" />
```